# How to access laravel flash data/message in ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to access laravel flash messages in the ajax request. I searched about it there are some solutions available, but i want to show them without reloading the page.

**What I'm Trying :**

In my controller i'm setting flash message

```
Session::flash('success', 'Record has been inserted successfully');
```

And

```
return response()->json([
    'success' => 'ok' // for status 200
]);
```

In Ajax

```
success: function(data){
    if(data.success){
        // reload the current page
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Framework/augLaravel3/public/index.php/user/add'; 
    }
}
```

In View

```
 @if (Session::has("success"))
   {{ Session::get("success") }}
 @endif
```

Above code is working properly, i just want to remove the reloading step, because i'm think it will be more convenient for complex or big application if i show the message through ajax (without page reload). But as i'm new to laravel so i don't know can i convert `session::flash` to json or not?

Can anyone guide me about this, that its possible? and it will be correct way if we access `session::flash` in ajax? I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of hardcoding html with the server's response like @Abbbas khan proposes, I would rather return a sub-view for flash messages and have the possibility to reuse that sub-view on any page.

**1. Create your flash messages sub-view:**
Create partials/flash-messages.blade.php

```
@if( Session::has("success") )
<div class="alert alert-success alert-block" role="alert">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
    {{ Session::get("success") }}
</div>
@endif

//Bonus: you can also use this subview for your error, warning, or info messages 
@if( Session::has("error") )
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-block" role="alert">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
    {{ Session::get("error") }}
</div>
@endif
```

**2. In your controller:** 
Define the success message you want and return your flash-messages sub-view

```
use Session;
use View;

Session::flash('success', 'File has been uploaded successfully!');
return View::make('partials/flash-messages');
```

**3. In your main view:**
Place a empty div at the location you'd like jquery to append your flash message

```
<div class="flash-message"></div>
```

**4. In your ajax code:**
Pass your sub-view as a html response and attach it to the div defined above

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'html', //Optional: type of data returned from server
    success: function(data) {
        $('div.flash-message').html(data);
    },
    ...
});
```

**5. Why I like this approach:**
With this server-side approach, you have your flash messages ready to be reused on any page. Your ajax code is also streamlined and you can also simply reuse it again on another page. The only thing you need to customise is the message content that you neatly define in your controller! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```php
// in php
if ($Validator->fails()) { 
    return Response::json([
        'message'=>'you have not inserted',
        'error' =>$Validator->errors()->toArray()
    ]);
} else {
    $this->flight->name = $request->name;
    $this->flight->detail = $request->detail; 
    $this->flight->save();
    return Response::json(['message'=>'you have inserted']); 
}
```

```js
// javascript, ajax success function
success: function(data){ 
    if(data.error){
        $('#main').html('<div class="alert alert-danger col-ssm-12" >' + data.message + '</div>');
        $('#nameid').html('<div class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12" >' + data.error.name + '</div>');
        $('#detailid').html('<div class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12">' + data.error.detail + '</div>');
        // location.reload('/');
    } else {
        $('#main').html('<div class="alert alert-info col-ssm-12" >' + data.message + '</div>');
    }
}
```